# which .toString is called in this case?

Tags: java

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25);
aThing.toString();
```

Is it the `toString` of the `Object` or `toString` of the `Integer`? (I think it's `Integer`'s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` of the `Integer`, is the one that is called.
You can easily prove that with an object of your own.

Comment: i couldn't, I put the "dot" `.` after the variable aThing in Eclipse and it showed a dropdown with `toString(): String - Object`....!!!

Comment: just write any object of you own, overwrite the toString() and you will see it. Don't let eclipse fool you with drop downs, it's the compiler that does the magic here.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer` class `toString()` will be called.  Method invocation will always be decided based on the Object type rather than reference type.

As Steve Kuo commented: except static methods.

Answer (score 1):

The one on the subclass is called, so the one on the `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` in the integer class is executed since it's the type of the instantiated class.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer's` `toString` is called. Which method implementation is called is always determined by the runtime type (class) of the object itself, not by the type of the variable it is assigned to. In the following code, both of the calls are equivalent.

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5);
Object o = i;

i.toString(); // "5"
o.toString(); // "5"
```

Methods that behave this way are called [Virtual Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method). All non-static methods in Java are virtual. They provide one of key mechanisms of [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).